# How do I set a delay between two actions in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

The program works like this:

1. I find an element by name
2. I click on the element, and it makes the element in 3 appear
3. I find the other element by link text
4. I click on it.

The problem that I have is that 3 happens too quick and the program is unable to locate the element. I think I need to put a delay or something in 3 that activates 4 when the element is found. Also I'm using Selenium if that helps.

I haven't been able to try anything because I have no idea of what I can do, because I'm very new to this.

Here  is the code:

```
atc = browser.find_element_by_name('commit')
atc.click()
checkout = browser.find_element_by_link_text('checkout now')
checkout.click()
```

Comment: Aside from use of `time` package, which is fine, have a look at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Import time module and use `time.sleep(2000)`.. I'm getting sleepy ;p

Comment: This has ***nothing*** to do with Selenium WebDriver. It is about sleep in Python and thus there are probably a gazillion duplicate questions (more than 10 years worth). The canonical for that is *[How do I get my Python program to sleep for 50 milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/377454)* (though none of the answers really address the common problem with a 16.66 ms time resolution for sub-second sleep) - probably not an issue in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked and answered on here several times. You could do

```
import time
time.sleep(5)   # Delays for 5 seconds.
```

taken from ([How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Time` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) library :

```
import time
atc = browser.find_element_by_name('commit')
atc.click()
time.sleep(5)
checkout = browser.find_element_by_link_text('checkout now')
checkout.click()
```

This impose a delay of 5 milliseconds between step 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

In your question:

> *"I think I need to put a delay or something in 3 that activates 4 when the element is found."*

I think the right option is the second one: "or something". You should to learn about to wait for an element, quoting [Selenium Wait docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

> if an element is not yet present in the DOM, a locate function will raise an ElementNotVisibleException exception. Using waits, we can solve this issue. Waiting provides some slack between actions performed - mostly locating an element or any other operation with the element.

An example on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851841

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :)