# selenium wait for certain amount of time and then execute script in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have some pages which take more than 60s to load so what I want to achieve is to wait for 60s, once the 60s is done close the loading using `execute_script("window.stop")` or suggest some better way if you have any.

PS - please don't suggest `driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)`
It is not what I am looking for.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you are looking for implicity_wait

Comment: Hi, have a look at implicait and explicit wait commands. This will be what you are looking for. Please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850842/finding-element-with-explicit-wait-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python

Answer (score 0):

*wait for certain amount of time*

[`sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) function is provided for such purposes in `time` module (part of standard library), it accepts value in seconds, so to wait 60 second just do:

```
import time
time.sleep(60)
```